# Prove a differential identity.

Tags: calculus

I need to compute the an integer power of an certain differential operator. The operator is just a product of a quadratic function and a differentiation operator. Since such the two operators do not commute we cannot just swap their order, ie move all the power functions to the left and all the differentiations to the right. Instead the result will be some sort of linear combination of differentiations of all orders. With the help of Mathematica I have established that 
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{\xi^2 \frac{d}{d \xi} \xi^2 \frac{d}{d \xi} \cdot \dots \cdot \xi^2 \frac{d}{d\xi}}_{p \quad times} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^p \frac{1}{i!} C^{p-1}_{i-1} p! \xi^{p+i} \frac{d^i}{d \xi^i}
\end{equation}
Is there a neat way of proving this result ?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can prove this using induction on $p$.